# metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary() inside a storyboard view controller returns null when embedded in SwiftUI code

Tags: ios, swiftui, storyboard, metalkit

I'm embedding a storyboard that uses a metaldevice inside a SwiftUI code.

This line:

```
let defaultLibrary = metalDevice.makeDefaultLibrary()!
```

Returns the following error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Does your app have a default metal library?

Comment: @jnpdx If I run the storyboard separately, it works but does not work when I insert it inside a swiftUI project. How to create a default metal library?

Comment: Have you written any metal code?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433380-makedefaultlibrary):

> **Return Value**: A new `MTLLibrary` instance if the method finds your app’s default library; otherwise `nil`.

The method couldn't finds your app’s default library, so it returned `nil`. You tried to force unwrap the result, hence the error.

This is probably happening because your metal library file is not in your current target. Select the .metal file then in the file inspector on the right, check under **Target Membership** and make sure the target you're building is selected.

Comment: My question is, why this happens, why does it not find my app's default metal library?